# Xcode how make free size of scrollview which depends on content

Tags: scrollview

I am making aт informative tableview app. I have 3 controllers:

1) Navigation Controller

2) Tableview controller with cells which include different information of different subjects.

3) View controller - which shows different information of EACH cells (big difference in size of information).

How can I use `ScrollView`, which shows the exact size of the view, depending on the size of the information? Each cell includes information of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Layout to have the scroll view automatically resize its `contentSize` to fit the contents. Let’s say you have a `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`. You add them as subviews to your scroll view, and then set up your constraints like this:

```
@"|[image]|"

@"|[textView]|"

@"V:|[imageView]-[textView]|"
```

Then set the content compression priority so that the text view doesn’t get squished:

```
[textView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                                          forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

I haven’t tested this code, but I believe it should work.